# In Debian Fluxbox, how do I fix the cursor on the second head?

Tags: debian, multi-monitor, cursor, fluxbox

I have the problem that my cursor icon doesn't get drawn on the secondary monitor of a two monitor setup. It looks like this on the main screen:

[image: working pointer]

But on the second screen it look like:

[image: broken pointer]

Interestingly, if I screenshot it with `gnome-screenshot -p` the cursor shows on the resulting picture (regardless of which monitor the window is on). This seems to imply that gnome knows what is there but fluxbox or the gpu driver doesn't.

I've tried using other cursor icons and while they show normally on the main monitor they do the same dashed line on the other screen. Happy to add any setting/conifg information would be helpful.

**Edit 1**

I was a little worried that it might be a driver issue and therefore not easily fixable. I have a "Sapphire Nitro r9 390" using the HDMI out on the 'bad' screen and displayport on the 'good' screen (ah, so maybe I could put both through with displayport. Worth a try anyway.). I'm using the proprietary "AMD Catalyst Linux Graphics Driver" `fglrx 15.20.3 [Sep  8 2015]`. The command `lspci | grep VGA` shows:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Hawaii PRO [Radeon R9 290] (rev 80)
```

While the driver info `fglrxinfo` shows:

```
display: :0  screen: 0
OpenGL vendor string: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: AMD Radeon (TM) R9 390 Series 
OpenGL version string: 4.5.13399 Compatibility Profile Context 15.201.1151
```

I'll try the DP for both and see if it helps.

**Edit 2**

I got another DP cable but it didn't seem to help. Mirroring the screens still has one with a normal cursor and one with the dots. I guess I'm stuck with it for the time being.

**Edit 3**

Updating to the latest Catalyst driver seems to have solved my problem, yay! The driver I used was the "Crimson Edition 15.12" dated 12/18/2015. The version info is now:

```
OpenGL vendor string: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: AMD Radeon (TM) R9 390 Series 
OpenGL version string: 4.5.13416 Compatibility Profile Context 15.302
```

Comment: This looks like a video driver bug. What exact model of graphics card do you have? Which outputs are the monitors connected to? Which driver (free or proprietary) and version of the video driver are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP has reported that
updating to the latest Catalyst driver seems to have solved the problem. 
The version info is now:

```
OpenGL vendor string: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: AMD Radeon (TM) R9 390 Series 
OpenGL version string: 4.5.13416 Compatibility Profile Context 15.302
```